# Ask some matrix eigenvalue inequalities.

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Let  $  \begin{bmatrix}
A& B   \\\\ B^*  &C
\end{bmatrix}$ be positive semidefinite, $A,C$ are of size $n\times n$.

Are the following plausible inequalities true? I have seen a lot of similar results, but for the following inequalities, I cannot locate them in the literature or find that they have been pointed out to be false.

1 $$\quad \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\begin{bmatrix}
A& B   \\\\ B^*  &C
\end{bmatrix}\le \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\left(\lambda_i(A)+\lambda_i(C)\right)\quad, $$
where $1\le k\le n$.

2 **Modified**
$$\quad \prod\limits_{i=1}^{2k}\lambda_i\begin{bmatrix}
A& B   \\\\ B^*  &C
\end{bmatrix}\le \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \lambda_i(A)\lambda_i(C) \quad, $$
where $1\le k\le n$.

3   $$ 2\lambda_i^{1/2}(B^*B)\le \lambda_i(A+C),$$ where $1\le k\le n$.

Here, $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ means the $i$th largest eigenvalue of $\cdot\quad$. Any references or counterexamples are appreciated.

Comment: it seems to me that your first majorization is reversed??

Comment: Probably you are saying $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\begin{bmatrix}
A&0   \\0  &C
\end{bmatrix}\le \sum\limits_{i=1}^k\lambda_i\begin{bmatrix}
A& B   \\ B^*  &C
\end{bmatrix}$, which is true.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Item 1** is true.  This is part of Problem 22 (b) in Section 3.5 of Horn and Johnson [HJ94], which states that for [Ky Fan norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Ky_Fan_norms) ||⋅|| (and in fact for any unitarily invariant norm) and a positive semidefinite block matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ B^* & C\end{pmatrix}$, it holds that $\left\|\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ B^* & C\end{pmatrix}\right\| \le \left\|\begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\| + \left\|\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & C\end{pmatrix}\right\|$.

([Aud06] contains a proof of a slight generalization of this inequality among other results.)

**Item 2 in the original question** is false by considering the case where *A*=*C*=*I*/2, *B*=0, and *k*=1, where *I* is the identity matrix.  (Did you mean to square the left-hand side?)

**Modified item 2** is false; see Willie Wong’s comment on this answer.

**Item 3** is false.  A simple counterexample is *n*=2, *i*=1,
$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$,
$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$,
$C=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.
Then $2\sqrt{\lambda_1(B^*B)}=2$ but *λ*<sub>1</sub>(*A*+*C*)=1.

References

[Aud06] Koenraad M. R. Audenaert.  A norm compression inequality for block partitioned positive semidefinite matrices.  *Linear Algebra and its Applications*, 413(1):155–176, Feb. 2006.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2005.08.017

[HJ94] Roger A. Horn, Charles R. Johnson.  *Topics in Matrix Analysis*.  Cambridge University Press, 1994.

Comment: +1 for your partial solution. I think I made a typo in Item 2, $k$ in the left hand side should be $2k$. When $k=n$, obviously item 2 is correct.

Comment: Modify the example by Tsuyoshi Ito: take $A = I, C = I/2$, $B = 0$, $n=2$, and $k = 1$. The LHS is $1\times 1 = 1$. The right hand side is $1 \times 1/2 = 1/2$. 

Comment: Yes, so I see that item 2 is not correct. 